# Why does Maven randomly stop seeing dependencies and how do I make it?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project using Jetty as a runner – in case it's relevant. My `pom.xml` file contains the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>7.17.3</version>
</dependency>
```

It used to be 7.14.2 and I upgraded it. After cleaning and refreshing, IntelliJ says some of the classes in one of the packages on which `transport` depends can't be found anymore. I tried forcing refreshes, cleaned the project multiple times, resolving dependencies... nothing, the project doesn't even build anymore because of those missing classes. I figured I'd downgrade it again, just in case I missed a breaking change somewhere but now I have the older version and the classes are still not there. I switched to a branch which I'm sure works and sure enough everything builds and runs just fine.

I checked with `mvn dependency:tree` and this is what comes up:

```
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:7.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:7.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:7.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure-sm:jar:7.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:jar:7.17.3:compile
```

`elasticsearch-x-content` is the package that is supposed to contain those classes and it shows up correctly (in the downgraded version too) but the classes are nowhere to be found.

I have had similar problems in the past where either Maven or IntelliJ IDEA randomly decide to stop seeing things that they were both happy to see just 20 minutes prior, and I never know how I manage to "fix" the issue each time so I don't have a repeatable series of incantations that I can offer as a clue.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I just tried a `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and no joy. I tried refreshing Maven from inside IntelliJ IDEA, nothing. I tried `mvn compile` and `mvn package -U` and nope.

**EDIT 2**: This is the error I'm getting on `mvn compile`:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/morpheu5/src/isaac/isaac-api/src/main/java/uk/ac/cam/cl/dtg/segue/etl/ElasticSearchIndexer.java:[20,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent
/Users/morpheu5/src/isaac/isaac-api/src/main/java/uk/ac/cam/cl/dtg/segue/etl/ElasticSearchIndexer.java:[21,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent
/Users/morpheu5/src/isaac/isaac-api/src/main/java/uk/ac/cam/cl/dtg/segue/etl/ElasticSearchIndexer.java:[22,40] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 3 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.623 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-26T13:56:15+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project isaac-api: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/morpheu5/src/isaac/isaac-api/src/main/java/uk/ac/cam/cl/dtg/segue/etl/ElasticSearchIndexer.java:[20,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent
[ERROR] /Users/morpheu5/src/isaac/isaac-api/src/main/java/uk/ac/cam/cl/dtg/segue/etl/ElasticSearchIndexer.java:[21,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent
[ERROR] /Users/morpheu5/src/isaac/isaac-api/src/main/java/uk/ac/cam/cl/dtg/segue/etl/ElasticSearchIndexer.java:[22,40] error: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: Always check on plain command line first...building... I suppose you had some network issues... which sometimes happens... in such cases just retry via `mvn package -U` to force downloading things...

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried that, no success.

Comment: Please run that command from plain command line and **NOT** from inside of IntelliJ ...

Comment: @khmarbaise That's what I've done.

Comment: I would check if those packages have been marked deprecated before and maybe now they have been removed...check the release notes??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running mvn compile from the command line and then refresing the project? Sometimes Intellij will bug out and not actually download a dependency even though it says it's trying to (happened to me a week ago).

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it still complains about missing packages.